# How to find current user's role in Laravel5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, roles

I am using package "romanbican/roles" in Laravel 5.2,
How to find current user's role ?

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $name=$user->name;
    $role = Role::find(......);   //How to find the  role  of current user ?
    return view('index', compact('name','role'));
}
```

## **eidt-1:**

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $name=$user->name;
        $role = $user->getRoles();
      //  return view('index', compact('name','role'));
        dd($role);
    }
```

result of edit-1:

```
Collection {#370 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

It's null,why is it?   @Mahfuz

User:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, HasRoleAndPermissionContract

{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, HasRoleAndPermission;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

}
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/check-if-user-has-admin-role

Comment: @LearningMode I got a Collection with nothing via dd().

Comment: @sunshine Do you have a `role` column in `users` table? If not, create one. If exist change `$role = $user->getRoles();` to `$role = $user->role;` and `dd($role);`

Answer (score 0):

first include HasRoleAndPermission Trait in your user model

then you can get all using this method

```
$user->getRoles()
```

it will return 
user all roles as collection.

Comment: I got a Collection with nothing via dd().